# Jquery getting the value of a parent element input when checking a child checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have this set of forms, when the user checks the input, I need to get the value that is outside this div, basically a parent div, try it to do it using .parent() and then find but could not make it work, not sure what do I am doing wrong, I have a js http://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/bCgeD/2/

This is my js:

```
                    function set_index_id_checkbox() {
                        $("input:checkbox[name='like']").each(function(index){
                            var currElem = $(this);
                            var prevLabel = currElem.next();
                            currElem.attr("id", this.id + index);
                            prevLabel.attr("for", prevLabel.attr("for") + index);
                        });
                    }

                    set_index_id_checkbox();


                    function getValues(){
                        $("input:checkbox[name='like']").click(function(){
                            if (this.checked) {
                               $(this).closest('.reply-form').find('.feedback_nid').text(this.value);
                            } else {
                              // ...
                            }
                       });
                    } getValues();
```

and this is my html:

```
        <input type="hidden" class="feedback_nid" value="form a 111">
        <input type="hidden" class="branch_nid" value="form a 222">

        <div class="block">
            <!-- value -->
            <span class="info-item float-left value">
                <span class="likes">value</span>
            </span><!-- /.value -->
            <!-- checkbox -->
            <div class="btn like-checkbox float-right">
                     <input id="like" class="like" type="checkbox" name="like" value="33">
                     <label class="like" for="like">like 1</label>
            </div><!-- /checkbox -->
        </div>

        </div>

        <div class="reply-form">
        <input type="hidden" class="feedback_nid" value="form a 111">
        <input type="hidden" class="branch_nid" value="form a 222">
        <div class="block">
            <!-- value -->
            <span class="info-item float-left value">
                <span class="likes">value</span>
            </span><!-- /.value -->
            <!-- checkbox -->
            <div class="btn like-checkbox float-right">
                     <input id="like" class="like" type="checkbox" name="like" value="45">
                     <label class="like" for="like">like 2</label>
            </div><!-- /checkbox -->
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="reply-form">
        <input type="hidden" class="feedback_nid" value="form a 111">
        <input type="hidden" class="branch_nid" value="form a 222">
        <div class="block">
            <!-- value -->
            <span class="info-item float-left value">
                <span class="likes">value</span>
            </span><!-- /.value -->
            <!-- checkbox -->
            <div class="btn like-checkbox float-right">
                     <input id="like" class="like" type="checkbox" name="like" value="66">
                     <label class="like" for="like">like 3</label>
            </div><!-- /checkbox -->
        </div>
        </div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are trying to set the `html of hidden input field..`

```
.find('.feedback_nid').html(this.value);
```

Input element's have no **inner HTML..**

Maybe you are looking for `.val(this.value)`

Also you can access the checkboxes using the `class like` instead of `attribute selector..`

I am instead populating the span with `class="likes"` and seems to be working fine..

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bCgeD/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try parents, parent will only search one div higher, but parents will search the file until it find the div if exist.

See the jquery documention:
[Jquery parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Answer (score 0):

The span with text `Value` in it is a different class  `likes` not the class `feedback_nid` you have set for a hidden input.

If you want the hidden input to have the same value use `val()` for the input and set the span using `text()`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gunderson/bCgeD/4/

I updated your example to work in jsfiddle.

The main change I made was traversing up the tree using .parent() until I got to the div that containes the value you're looking for. Additionally I updated your syntax to pull the value out of the hidden field using jquery.val();

```
 function getValues(){
    $("input:checkbox[name='like']").click(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
           var value = $(this).parent().parent().parent()
               .find('.feedback_nid').val();
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".likes").text(value);
        } else {
          // ...
        }
   });
} getValues();
```

Comment: You can also uses parents instead off two times parent()